# Yii2 parse action name from referer url

Tags: yii2

I want to check condition on previous action name. I got the previous action url from `Yii::$app->request->referrer`.
Now i want to parse only action name Or there is another way to directly get referer action name.

Answer (score 11):

You can easily parse the URL by mocking a `Request` object and passing it to the `UrlManger`.

Imagine we have URL `http://example.com/user/42`, and `UrlManager` has the following rule: `['user/<id:\d+>' => 'user/view']`

```
$request = new Request(['url' => parse_url(Yii::$app->request->referrer, PHP_URL_PATH)]);
$url = Yii::$app->urlManager->parseRequest($request);
var_dump($url); // ['user/view', 'id' => 42]
```

Cool, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$referrerUrl = trim(Yii::$app->request->referrer, '/');
$urlParts = parse_url($referrerUrl);
$controller_name = explode('/', $urlParts['path'])[1];
$action_name = explode('/', $urlParts['path'])[2];`
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While just code may answer the question, adding an explanation will significantly improve the quality of the answer.